# Create hosting accounts on the fly

Tags: windows, user-accounts, remote-access

Using VB, VBScript, ASP.Net or similar, on a Windows dedicated server, is it possible to create a new hosting account on my server and how challenging is it? With this, is it also possible to add a new domain name and point it at that particular account?

I have an online photo portfolio service, when a user creates a new portfolio, I want my website to create a new hosting account for them and point their domain at it, on-the-fly. At the mo, I have to do it and it's a bore!

Any suggestions, tips, links or plugins gratefully received.

Comment: Note Windows has certain licensing restrictions when you start creating accounts and using Windows technologies to authentication people. This might already be covered, but it is a consideration you should look into before building the system out. If you'll be hosting websites for other people that requires SPLA, and you need to be an MS Partner to get that. There are many more details than I could fit in a comment, contact Microsoft Licensing for all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great reference to account creation scripting would be [How to create Active Directory user account with powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/60992/how-to-create-active-directory-user-account-with-powershell)

Powershell will let you access just about anything that's a library call.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible!

We create apache vhosts by running scripts and passing variables in from a ruby on rails app. You can do a similar workflow from your application. You'll also need some scripting to setup ftp and the like. You'll want to be very careful your process silo's each site from the other for security purposes, in linux this is accomplished using chroot, suexec, and (for us) phpfpm.

- [Creating a new website programmatically on IIS using ASP.NET and C#](http://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/)
- [You can try passing variables to a script like iisweb.vbs (IIS6)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aee71684-36c0-40e1-b387-a19d2d0509f0.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567301/how-can-i-programmatically-create-new-sites-in-iis-6)

Comment: Cool thanks. Well you answered my question (how challenging is it), too challenging for me...

Comment: @MartinG perhaps you want to look into Powershell? They are a lot of good scripts around to refernce for that.

Comment: @Jeff great idea...http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/

Comment: Aagggh, that looks a little more my style of reading, thanks Jeff. I will study this over the next week or so and try and accomplish something.