# Importing Users into Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Active Directory user account with powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/60992/how-to-create-active-directory-user-account-with-powershell)

I'm trying to add some users onto my active directory through PowerShell I would be greatful if anyone could provide me with a piece of code or any other method of how I could do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you say "any other method" I'm taking it as "aside from Powershell". I generally use CSV files to import and export users to and from AD. You can find more information on technet here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727091.aspx.

A question in regards to exporting via Powershell has been asked over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381943/how-to-export-csv-of-active-directory-objects. This may go some way to helping you.

Edit: Infact this may be more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911402/how-do-you-add-users-from-a-csv-file-to-active-directory-ad-and-exchange-using (Apologies for the link bombing).