# DSADD error, I can't see it

Tags: active-directory

I've been given the task of creating all the new year 7's AD accounts and I thought just use DSADD and put together a script using excel

Anyway I've hit a snag, it keeps erroring out with "*cn=Test User,ou=Year7,ou=SHS Users,dc=shs,dc=local directory or object not found*"

here's my script

```
dsadd User "cn=Test User,ou=Year7,ou=SHS Users,dc=shs,dc=local" -samid p9000 -upn p9000@shs.local -pwd password -mustchpwd yes -fn test -ln user -email p9000@springwoodhighschool.co.uk -desc test-form -hmdir \\fileserver\p9000 -hmdrv N: -empid 19482 -memberof "cn=Students,ou=Groups,ou=SHS Users,dn=shs,dn=local" "cn=Year7,ou=Groups,ou=SHS Users,dn=shs,dn=local"
```

I've checked the OU names and locations and everything obvious it's definitely shs.local>SHS Users>Year7

Were using server 2008

I know its probably obvious but I tired and not seeing it

Any Help appreciated.

EDIT

**PLEASE IGNORE QUESTION**: I Realised there isn't a space between SHS User, I really need to catch up on some sleep, Sorry all for any time wasted

P.S. Greg you are also right that does need changing

Comment: are you 100% sure about that DN? Try adding a user through the (GUI) tools and then dumping the account to verify.

Comment: You may also want to check out the accepted answer [on this similar question](http://serverfault.com/questions/60992/how-to-create-active-directory-user-account-with-powershell) for an alternate way of creating the account (PowerShell's `New-ADUser` versus `dsadd`).  What you're doing *should* work just fine, but I think `New-ADUser` is "The New Hotness" for this :-)

Comment: I'm assuming "cn=Students,ou=Groups,ou=SHS Users,dn=shs,dn=local" probably should be: "cn=Students,ou=Groups,ou=SHS Users,DC=shs,DC=local"

Comment: Please either post an answer and mark it accepted, or remove this question.